# Paypal not capturing one element of shopping cart

Tags: php, paypal

A friend has a simple Paypal form set up to sell tickets for a festival. It has 3 required dropdowns where users choose a workshop to take. Live form is here: http://gospelrising.com/festival-2013/tickets

Payments go through and everything seems fine but he's noticed that the value for the 3rd dropdown isn't being captured.

What could be causing this issue? I've had a look at the HTML and it seems fine. I'm really not familiar with the nuances of Paypal so help appreciated.

Comment: Are you positive that all three are being passed?  We can't see your paypal scripting unless you show us.

Comment: Just tried your form in firefox and all three sessions were listed in paypal.

Comment: So are you suggesting it could be a browser specific issue Hugo?